# Why does the value of $HOME vary between Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04 in a script using sudo

Tags: ubuntu, bash-scripting, sh

On Windows 10 v1909, I am using WSL *(Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04: 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft x86_64 GNU/Linux)* and I noticed the value of `$HOME` within an arbitrary script varies between Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 when executed using `sudo`.

- **Ubuntu 18.04:** `test.sh`

  ```bash
  echo $HOME
    Home: /home/khan
  ```

  [image: ScreenShot Ubuntu 18.04]
- **Ubuntu 20.04:** `test.sh`

  ```bash
  echo $HOME
    Home: /root
  ```

  [image: ScreenShot Ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: Check [`man 5 sudoers`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.0/sudoers.man.html#SUDOERS_OPTIONS) for the description of `always_set_home` and related options. Can it be the config differs? Investigate.

Comment: Home: /root.  Dude, you are clearly logged in as the physical root user in ubuntu 20.. you are logged in as "khan" in 18.04.  You don't have different home directories.  You are logged in as two different accounts.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it's not possible to log in as `root` on Ubuntu... it's an intentionally locked account.  Even if a user could log in as `root`, `sudo` would then have no usage, and the terminal screenshots show the OP is logged into their user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the answer from another SO site:

> For years, Ubuntu has shipped a patched version of sudo that preserves
> $HOME by default. Besides Ubuntu and its derivatives, very few other
> operating systems (perhaps no others) do this. It has been decided
> that this causes more problems than it solves, and starting in Ubuntu
> 19.10, $HOME is no longer one of the few environment variables sudo preserves.

Original Answer: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187000/870211)